# How to count specific terms in tokenized sentences wthin a pandas df

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, nlp, nltk

I'm new to Python and nltk, so I would really appreciate your input on the following problem.

**Goal:**

I want to search and count the occurrence of specific terminology in tokenized sentences which are stored in a pandas DataFrame. The terms I'm searching for are stored in a list of strings. The output should be saved in a new column.

Since the words I'm searching for are grammatically inflected (e.g. cats instead of cat) I need a solution which not only displays exact matches. I guess stemming the data and searching for specific stems would be a proper approach but let's assume this is not an option here, as we would still have semantic overlaps.

**What I tried so far:**

In order to further handle the data I preprocessed the data while following these steps:

1. Put everything in lower case
2. Remove punctuation
3. Tokenization
4. Remove stop words

I tried searching for single terms with `str.count('cat')` but this doesn't do the trick and the data is marked as missing with `NaN`. Additionally, I don't know how to iterate over the search word list in an efficient way while using pandas.

**My code so far:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import re
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

# Function to remove punctuation
def remove_punctuation(text):
    return re.sub(r'[^\w\s]','',text)


# Target data where strings should be searched and counted
data = {'txt_body': ['Ab likes dogs.', 'Bc likes cats.',
                     'De likes cats and dogs.', 'Fg likes cats, dogs and cows.',
                     'Hi has two grey cats, a brown cat and two dogs.']}


df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

# Search words stored in a list of strings
search_words = ['dog', 'cat', 'cow']

# Store stopwords from nltk.corpus
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))

# Data preprocessing
df['txt_body'] = df['txt_body'].apply(lambda x: x.lower())
df['txt_body'] = df['txt_body'].apply(remove_punctuation)
df['txt_body'] = df['txt_body'].fillna("").map(word_tokenize)
df['txt_body'] = df['txt_body'].apply(lambda x: [word for word in x if word not in stop_words])

# Here is the problem space
df['search_count'] = df['txt_body'].str.count('cat')



print(df.head())
```

**Expected output:**

```
                                       txt_body  search_count
0                             [ab, likes, dogs]             1
1                             [bc, likes, cats]             1
2                       [de, likes, cats, dogs]             2
3                 [fg, likes, cats, dogs, cows]             3
4  [hi, two, grey, cats, brown, cat, two, dogs]             3
```

Comment: You want to count prefixes? Otherwise you'll have to lemmatize or do some stemming on the the tokens...

Comment: Hi! Yes, it would be fine to count only parts of the actual word. Lemmatizing are a bit of an issue since, I'm looking for a solution which could also be applied with a non-english data set. But stemming should be not an issue... What would you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple solution would be this:

```
def count_occurence(l, s):
    counter = 0
    for item in l:
        if s in item:
            counter += 1
    return counter

df['search_count'] = df.apply(lambda row: count_occurence(row.txt_body, 'cat'),1)
```

You could then further decide how to define the count_occurence function. And, to search for the whole search_words, something like this will do the job, although it is probably not the most efficient:

```
def count_search_words(l, search_words):
    counter = 0
    for s in search_words:
        counter += count_occurence(l, s)
    return counter

df['search_count'] = df.apply(lambda row: count_search_words(row.txt_body, search_words),1)
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that works for a single string. How would you iterate over the strings in the `search_words` list and summarize the results for all three terms? I'm having trouble finding a proper solution here.

Comment: Ah sorry. I didn't refresh the the page. Yes, it definitely works. Thanks again! The efficiency question is definitely a relevant one, since I'm planning to apply this with a rather large data set. But the preprocessing already takes some time, so it should be fine for now. Do you have any hunch, how a more efficient approach might look like?

Comment: It will probably be fine as long as search_words does not get huge.